# Forcing Oracle to do distinct last

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, distinct

I have a quite complicated view (using several layers of views across several database links) which takes a second to return all of it's rows. But, when I ask for distinct rows, it takes considerably more time. I stopped waiting after 4 minutes.

To make my self as clear as possible:

```
select a, b from compicated_view; -- takes 1 sec (returns 6 rows)
select distinct a, b from compicated_view; -- takes at least 4 minutes
```

I find that pretty weird, but hey, that's how it is. I guess Oracle messed something up when planing that query. Now, is there a way to force Oracle to first finish the select without distinct, and then do a "select distinct *" on the results? I looked into optimizer hints, but I can't find anything about hinting the order in which distinct is applied (this is first time I'm optimizing a query, obviously :-/).

I'm using Oracle SQl Developer on Oracle 10g EE.

Comment: Are you sure "All" rows were returned in the 1 sec run? When working with SQL developer the engine will return a partial record set and display it. As you scroll down, more records become available and amended to the display.  So you have the appearance that the records have been returned, when infact, only a subset has.

Comment: @xQbert Yup, it's just 6 rows.

Comment: What's the execution plans look like for both?

Comment: It's huge, HTML export of execution plan has 335 kB for query with distinct and 338 kB for query without distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A,B FROM (
   SELECT A,B FROM COMPLICATED_VIEW 
   WHERE rownum > 0 );
```

this forces to materialize the subquery and prevents from view merging/predicate pushing, and likely from changing the original plan of the view.
You may also try NO_MERGE hint:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(alias) */ 
     DISTINCT a,b
FROM ( 
   SELECT a,b FROM COMPLICATED_VIEW 
) alias
```

Comment: The where rownum trick worked. NO_MERGE didn't help. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted details... try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A,B
FROM
(SELECT A,B FROM COMPLICATED_VIEW);
```

Comment: Tried that, also takes forever to execute. What kind of details would you like? I can post execution plans on pastebin if you wish.

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT A,B FROM (SELECT A,B FROM COMPLICATED_VIEW WHERE rownum > 0 );`, this forces to materialize the subquery and prevents from view merging/predicate pushing, and likely from changing the original plan of the view. You may also try NO_MERGE hint: `SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(alias) */ DISTINCT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM COMPLICATED_VIEW ) alias`

Comment: @kordirko Disabling complex view merging is almost certainly the right approach.  You should post that comment as an answer.